# adding list's elements respect to a field of the elements in Scala

Tags: scala, playscalajs

In Scala I have the next command:

```
  lPServ <- Pservs.getAll(.....some logical condition.....)
```

each element of lPserv has a "price" and "quantity" fields. For this list, I need to get the total of adding each

```
         e.price * e.quantity
```

where e is element of lPServ. Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Pservs is:

```
case class Pservs(price: Int, quantity: Double)
```

then:

```
( for { e <- Seq(Pservs(12, 3), Pservs(6, 3)) } yield e.price * e.quantity ).sum
```